# discord.py (rewrite) How can I narrow a commands use ability to a single channel?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make this code work only in a specific channel. It just sends a ton of errors when I try to do the command in the right channel. Ill add my imports if you want to test it. Last time I tried to ask this question it got denied. I still don't know what to do and just need a little help as i'm new to coding a discord bot.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import os
import random
import asyncio
from asyncio import gather    
        
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
        
@client.command()
    async def car(ctx):
            pictures = [
            'https://car-images.bauersecure.com/pagefiles/78294/la_auto_show_11.jpg',
            'http://www.azstreetcustom.com/uploads/2/7/8/9/2789892/az-street-custom-gt40-2_orig.jpg',
            'http://tenwheel.com/imgs/a/b/l/t/z/1967_firebird_1968_69_70_2000_camaro_blended_custom_supercharged_street_car_1_lgw.jpg',
            'https://rthirtytwotaka.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/dsc_0019.jpg',
            'http://speedhunters-wp-production.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/fluke27.jpg',
            'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pCt0KXC1tng/maxresdefault.jpg',
            'https://i2.wp.com/www.tunedinternational.com/featurecars/dorift/02.jpg',
            'http://i.imgur.com/nEbyV82.jpg',
            'https://cdn.hiconsumption.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Affordable-Vintage-Japanese-Cars-0-Hero-1087x725.jpg',
            'http://speedhunters-wp-production.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/IMG_0268.jpg',
            'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Y-moGXK2zLk/maxresdefault.jpg',
            'https://www.topgear.com/sites/default/files/images/big-read/carousel/2016/03/568cd4ab437c6557c583a6f4a4feb6d1/3carguyscarouselmarch2016.jpg'
            ]
            channel = discord.utils.get()
            if channel == 705161333972140072:
                await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
                await ctx.send(f'{random.choice(pictures)}')
    
client.run('token')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a few changes in the command function:

1. Fix indentation
2. Use `ctx.channel.id` instead of `channel`and `discord.utils.get()`
3. Rather than purging, delete the command msg

---

```
@client.command()
async def car(ctx):
    pictures = [
    'https://car-images.bauersecure.com/pagefiles/78294/la_auto_show_11.jpg',
    'http://www.azstreetcustom.com/uploads/2/7/8/9/2789892/az-street-custom-gt40-2_orig.jpg',
    'http://tenwheel.com/imgs/a/b/l/t/z/1967_firebird_1968_69_70_2000_camaro_blended_custom_supercharged_street_car_1_lgw.jpg',
    'https://rthirtytwotaka.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/dsc_0019.jpg',
    'http://speedhunters-wp-production.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/fluke27.jpg',
    'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pCt0KXC1tng/maxresdefault.jpg',
    'https://i2.wp.com/www.tunedinternational.com/featurecars/dorift/02.jpg',
    'http://i.imgur.com/nEbyV82.jpg',
    'https://cdn.hiconsumption.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Affordable-Vintage-Japanese-Cars-0-Hero-1087x725.jpg',
    'http://speedhunters-wp-production.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/IMG_0268.jpg',
    'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Y-moGXK2zLk/maxresdefault.jpg',
    'https://www.topgear.com/sites/default/files/images/big-read/carousel/2016/03/568cd4ab437c6557c583a6f4a4feb6d1/3carguyscarouselmarch2016.jpg'
    ]
    if ctx.channel.id == 705161333972140072:
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.send(random.choice(pictures))

client.run('token')
```

You can also use [checks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.check)